# Multiple variables in web query Power BI

Tags: web-scraping, pagination, powerbi-desktop

I am web scraping data from the following URL in Power BI:

https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;dismissal=1;filter=advanced;orderby=batted_score;page=2;team=7;template=results;type=batting;view=innings

The URL uses pagination (see above) and to extract all the pages I am using list.generate

NOW TO THE ISSUE.

There are 9 different dismissal's. I created a custom column (1 to 9) and want power query to take that column in the url and pull data accordingly as shown below

[Desired Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sBI3.png)

When I try to enter the custom column in the url it gives me token ',' expected error (see below)

```
(PageStart)=>

let 

Source= Web.BrowserContents("https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;dismissal=" #Table.Column(Dismissal,"Dismissal") ";filter=advanced;orderby=batted_score;page="&Number.ToText(PageStart)&";team=7;template=results;type=batting;view=innings"), 
#"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, {"Column2", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, {"Column3", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}, {"Column4", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(4)"}, {"Column5", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(5)"}, {"Column6", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(6)"}, {"Column7", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(7)"}, {"Column8", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(8)"}, {"Column9", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(9)"}, {"Column10", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(10)"}, {"Column11", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(11)"}, {"Column12", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(12)"}, {"Column13", "TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR > :nth-child(13)"}}, [RowSelector="TABLE.engineTable:nth-child(5) > * > TR"]), 
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Extracted Table From Html", [PromoteAllScalars=true]), 
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Player", type text}, {"Runs", Int64.Type}, {"Mins", type text}, {"BF", Int64.Type}, {"4s", Int64.Type}, {"6s", Int64.Type}, {"SR", type number}, {"Inns", Int64.Type}, {"", type text}, {"Opposition", type text}, {"Ground", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"_1", type text}}) 

in 

#"Changed Type"
```

thank you and appreciated for the help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.